# Select query shows nohostavailableexception without partition key in where condition

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to read rows from dev center and client apis but if i "select *" for all 2k rows it shows no host available exception in query trace though it has all the nodes up in cluster. but if i keep partition key in where condition it doesn't show any error. Can anyone help in finding the issue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably hitting timeouts. Doing `select * from` with no where clause is **not** a good idea as you'll potentially be hitting every node in your cluster.
If this is just for testing, you can bump up your [read timeouts](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__read_request_timeout_in_ms) (`read_request_timeout_in_ms`) in the yaml but you don't want to use a query like that in production.

For further insight use the [query tracing](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcQueryTrace.html) feature in Dev Center which is pretty nice in the latest releases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @phact , the table just has 2k rows with just one partition key so i was thinking it  should not overload the cluster.  its basically a test i did.. Actual issue we had is we got many errors in client saying "nohostavailableexception"  .. i see all nodes up and running.. so confused on what the issue can be.. i checked mem and cpu load all looks normal to me..   any information on this will be very helpful. thanks.